# Sum vector elements homorphically

Tags: homomorphic-encryption

I'm looking for the homomorphic version of the following (I'm using Python here):

```
$ a = [1,2,3]
$ s = sum(a)  
$ print(s)
6
```

Is there an open source fully homomorphic library which is able to do $sum(vector)$? So far I just found libraries allowing operations with input-output either only vectorial or only integer. Here I'm asking for a vector to integer operation.

Of course there is another way, namely encrypting every integer element of $a$ individually, summing in the encrypted domain, and then decrypt the result. Since I would like to take advantage of the speed of vector batching, I'm not considering this as a good solution.

Comment: "I would like to take advantage of the speed of vector batching"; what is it about Paillier encrypting each individual element of the vector that makes 'vector batching' difficult?

Comment: I'm not aware of libraries capable of quickly handling vectors of encrypted integers (instead of encrypted vectors of integers), but I'm happy to be proved wrong here. Also, I need fully homomorphic encryption, I will make this clear in the question.

Comment: I am not aware of schemes whose plaintext space is $\mathbb{Z}^n$ and that allow us to create ciphertexts encrypting values in $\mathbb{Z}$... But there are schemes that encrypt natively vectors and matrices and we can perform vector-matrix products. If you have several vectors $a_i$'s, you can put them in the columns of a matrix $A$, encrypt the vector $v = (1, 1, ..., 1)$, and do $v\cdot A$ to get $(sum(a_1), ..., sum(a_n))$. Well, it is already something...

Comment: NTRU enables [generic bit-sliced](https://eprint.iacr.org/2014/039.pdf) however, you need to find a way to combine the 2048 results.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there are many libraries that use lattices and LWE schemes to implement fully homomorphic Encryptions.

This is a set, Most of them is in C++ and Only one by MSFT is C#, But in all cases you can port the code to python aftor compiling:

1. [HElib](https://github.com/homenc/HElib) in C++
2. [SEAL By MicroSoft](https://github.com/microsoft/SEAL) C++/C#
3. [Palisade](https://gitlab.com/palisade/palisade-release) C++
4. [FHEW](https://github.com/lducas/FHEW) C/C++
5. [TFHE](https://tfhe.github.io/tfhe/) C++
6. [NFLib](https://github.com/quarkslab/NFLlib) C++

Note: The set in no particular order.

Comment: Did you see the Hilder's comment? The OP asking in $\mathbb{Z}^n$. OP doesn't ask for the list of libraries.

Comment: Ok, You are right, my answer is irrelevant.  but I think the original question needes updates. Any way KNN encryption scheme (not the classification) Allows multiplication of two encrypted values and the result is a vector. Is this what question you asks for ?

Comment: No, he just wants to add but wants to use parallelization. TheElGamal, Paillier may be enough for him, however, they have not vector to integer.

Comment: Then his question can be solved using divide and conquer. The can split his data into multiple parts, each part is sent a processor then adds them... There are like a ton of methods to execute similar approaches? More importantly, I think he is asking in the wrong place !!!

Comment: Do you know the message size of 1-bit encryption? He is not looking for software way. AFAIK, NTRU enables [generic bit-sliced](https://eprint.iacr.org/2014/039.pdf). They run 2048 encryption altogether.